# How to match data from 2 different sheets and pull if there is a match in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with 2 different sheets in excel one is testData and the other is QLD. I need to match the ID in both sheets and if there is a match pull the Price column for the QLDsheet. Currently the data structure is like this

testData

```
A)ProductID | B)PriceMatch
      S100  |   Need to match
      S200  |   Need to match
      S300  |   Need to match
```

---

QLD

```
A) ProductID | B)Price
      S100   |   $100
      S200   |   $200
      S300   |   $300
```

Comment: Have you heard of `vlookup`?

Comment: yes. I've tried something like this using vlookup `=V(A:TestData,MATCH(,A:QLD,0)=B)` Didn't quite work. Not sure what im missing. Sorry im very new to excel.

Comment: It should definitely work with `vlookup`. You need to press the `alt+f4` button somewhere too. Have you done that? You should use te full formula = `vlookup` not `V`

Comment: Changed the vlookup up and tried to use the function from the formulas tab. But I'm not sure how to select columns from 2 different sheets.

Comment: Have you seen the instructional video on the official documentation page for the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)?

Answer (score 0):

Index/match will work wonders for you

syntax

```
 {=index('range where return value is <price>', match('test value', 'range where test value is', 0))}
```

remember to enter using control+shift+enter

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula in testData in B1

=INDEX(QLD!$B:$B; MATCH(testData!$A1; QLD!$B:$B; 0);COLUMNS($A:A))